# Defining the arguments for the functions inside the cython class and fast integral calculation in cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, cython

I am a newbie with cython and trying to convert a python class to **cython**. I don't know how I should define argument `z` in **instance Da**, in the way that it can deal with both **numpy.array** or just a single `float` number.

```
cdef class Cosmology(object):
    cdef double omega_m, omega_lam, omega_c  

    def __init__(self,double omega_m=0.3,double omega_lam=0.7):
        self.omega_m = omega_m
        self.omega_lam = omega_lam
        self.omega_c = (1. - omega_m - omega_lam)


    cpdef double a(self, double z):
        cdef double a
        return 1./(1+z)

    cpdef double E(self, double a):
        cdef double E
        return (self.omega_m*a**(-3) + self.omega_c*a**(-2) + self.omega_lam)**0.5

    cpdef double __angKernel(self, double x):
        cdef __angKernel:
        """Integration kernel"""
        return self.E(x**-1)**-1

    cpdef double Da(self, double z, double z_ref=0):
        cdef double Da
        if isinstance(z, np.ndarray):
            da = np.zeros_like(z)
            for i in range(len(da)):
                da[i] = self.Da(z[i], z_ref)
            return da
        else:
            if z < 0:
                raise ValueError("Redshift z must not be negative")
            if z < z_ref:
                raise ValueError("Redshift z must not be smaller than the reference redshift")

            d = integrate.quad(self.__angKernel, z_ref+1, z+1,epsrel=1.e-6, epsabs=1.e-12)
            rk = (abs(self.omega_c))**0.5
            if (rk*d[0] > 0.01):
                if self.omega_c > 0:
                    d[0] = sinh(rk*d[0])/rk
                if self.omega_c < 0:
                    d[0] = sin(rk*d[0])/rk
            return d[0]/(1+z)
```

I also wonder whether I convert all the arguments correctly into cython argument? I want to change my original python code to improve the speed of calculation. One of the bottleneck in my code I reckon, should be `integrate.quad`. Is there any substitution for this function in `cython` which helps to speed up the performance of my code?

```
cdef class halo_positions(object):
     cdef double x = None
     cdef double y = None
     def __init__(self,numpy.ndarray[double, ndim=1] positions):
         self.x = positions[0]
         self.y = positions[1]
```

And if I want to pass an array to `halo_positions` instance is it a right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your class is defined as `cdef` it will be accessible only in Cython (not in Python) making it unnecessary and not efficient to use `cpdef` and `def` for the class methods. You can convert them all to `cdef`.

When you tell that `z` is `double`, it will accept only a `double`. If you want this argument to be of two different types, you should keep its type undeclared, but this will directly affect the loop performance when `z` is a `ndarray`.

Alternatively you could use `double *` and pass the size of it, when the size is `1` it is a double, when the size is `>1` an array. The function would be:

```
cdef double Da(self, int size, double *z, double z_ref=0):
    if size>1:
        da = np.zeros(size)
        for i in range(size):
            da[i] = self.Da(1, &z[i], z_ref)
        return da
    else:
        if z[0] < 0:
            raise ValueError("Redshift z must not be negative")
        if z[0] < z_ref:
            raise ValueError("Redshift z must not be smaller than the reference redshift")

        d = integrate.quad(self.__angKernel, z_ref+1, z[0]+1,
                           epsrel=1.e-6, epsabs=1.e-12)
        rk = (abs(self.omega_c))**0.5
        if (rk*d[0] > 0.01):
            if self.omega_c > 0:
                d[0] = sinh(rk*d[0])/rk
            if self.omega_c < 0:
                d[0] = sin(rk*d[0])/rk
        return d[0]/(1+z[0])
```

Comment: so I assume I have to declare `double rk` and what about `epsrel` and `epsabs`. My other question is whether the scipy integral can be substitute with something equivalent in cython? Because so far I think that is why the speed of my code is very low.

Comment: @Dalek you actually have to questions, the first one is commented in this answer. For the second one, if I understood, do you want to integrate a vector valued function? ([like in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17070333/832621))

Comment: @Dalek `epsrel` and `epsabs` are tolerances for the numerical integration error, the lower these values the more precise the numerical integration gets...

Comment: Indeed `z` is actually a `1D` array with the shape of (1500,) and I need to integrate over each component of this array in a loop with `range(24000)`, so the speed of my code is very low so that is why I want to convert it to cython.

Comment: @Dalek I have an implementation using a Trapezoidal rule or an nth-order polynomial rule to perform such vector valued integration, [check this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17522695/832621)

Comment: in the example you have given it seems it computes an array of functions, however my problem is to give an array of points for one given function. In addition I don't quite understand how you define the lower and upper limit of integral

Comment: @Dalek the integration limits are defined in `xs = np.linspace(0.,20.,33)`... let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55246/discussion-between-saullo-castro-and-dalek).

Comment: The example you sent me, you integrated over different function with the same interval my problem is that I want to integrate over same function with different input parameter 24000 times with different upper integration limits which changes in a loop for like 1500 points. Is there any way to optimize it, since I want to use this again in `Markov Chain Monte Carlo`.

Comment: @Dalek, this seems to be a different question than the one you originally asked, you could create this new question giving more details about the integration that you want...

Comment: I will write another question.